# Adding additional Apache2 rewrites without infinite redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

I currently have the following in a `.htaccess` file to rewrite the `.php` extention:

```
# /var/www/html/help/.htaccess

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo excluding POST requests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L,NE]

# To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Which works as expected. However I'm looking to add some additional rewrites, such as redirecting `/help/open` to `/help/submit`. Everything I've tried seems to end with infinite redirects from /help/open -> /help/submit and back.

```
RewriteRule open.php /help/submit [R=302,NE,L]
RewriteRule submit /help/open.php [L]
```

Can someone advise how I could implement additional URL rewrites here without resulting in infinite loops?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting infinite loop error because your rules  redirect the destination file `help/open.php` to itself . You can use an `END` flag in your second rule to fix this problem.

```
RewriteRule open.php /help/submit [R=302,NE,L]
RewriteRule submit /help/open.php [END]
```

Note : The `END` flag only works on Apache version 2.4 or higher. If you are using an older version of Apache then use the following solution instead

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule open.php /help/submit [R=302,NE,L]
RewriteRule submit /help/open.php [L]
```